# How to dispose media files after accessing its properties?

Tags: c#, winforms

I need to access at least 100 of media files(video) and checking through their properties. eg. date modified, camera model/maker then if im done with it, i need to dispose/release this media files. is there a media.Dispose() method.

```
Shell32.Shell shell;
shell = new Shell32.Shell();
Shell32.Folder objFolder;
Shell32.FolderItem folderItem;
string stringFullFileName, model, maker;

foreach (FileInfo files in MyFolder)
{
     stringFullFileName=files.FullName.ToString();

     objFolder = shell.NameSpace(Path.GetDirectoryName(stringFullFileName));
     folderItem = objFolder.ParseName(Path.GetFileName(stringFullFileName));

     model = objFolder.GetDetailsOf(folderItem, 30);
     maker = objFolder.GetDetailsOf(folderItem, 32);

     //Marshal.ReleaseComObject(objFolder); //doesnt dispose
     //Marshal.ReleaseComObject(folderItem); //doesnt dispose

     File.Move(stringFullFileName, newPath); //It says "The process cant access the file 
     because it is being used by another process"
}
```

i need File.Move, not File.Copy.

Comment: Why not use a `using` statement with the `files` in question? That way you could work with the FileInfo object direct and it should dispose on the end of using?

Comment: but i need to access those video properties, like date created/modified...etc. In image file, its simple but in video file, i think it needs different approach

Comment: So, you trying to loop through a list of files within a directory, fetching data on each file at that same time, then move the file and move on, right?

Comment: yes its correct. i need to move that file in a new directory after fetching data on it.

Comment: I still dont understand why you cant just use a simple FileInfo / DirectoryInfo for this, something like:             
`foreach (var file in new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\VideoFolder").GetFiles())
            {
                var creationTime = file.CreationTime;
                file.MoveTo(@"C:\Trash\");
            }`

Answer (score 0):

I have 2 possible solutions for you:

1 - Unless you need to import the Shell assembly for some reason, I don't see why you can't just use a `DirectoryInfo` / `FileInfo` objects: i.e.

```
        foreach (var file in new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\VideoFolder").GetFiles())
        {
            //Get the file information that you need here...
            var creationTime = file.CreationTime;
            //Move the file
            file.MoveTo(@"C:\Trash\");
        }
```

2 - If you have to keep the code as is for some reason, why not just move the file direct (it's already a `FileInfo` Object)? i.e. 
Instead of this line:

```
File.Move(stringFullFileName, newPath); //It says "The process cant access the file
```

Have this:

```
files.Move(newPath);
```

Comment: i tried what you have suggested, i got the same error "IOException" . Its because, after fetching data on a file, the video file itself will be renamed dynamically. The video was renamed from MOV_1 to MyMOV_01. Thats why i need to dispose this video file before moving it to new location